# ajax call does not update

Tags: ajax, call

I made an Ajax call. 
It shows the data on my site, but it does not update it automatically(without pressing f5(refreshing my site)) if I change it in the database.

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    getname();
})
function getname(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '../php/clas/name.php',
            data: 'type=getthename',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(responseOrderData){
                var showOrderData = '';
                var rows = 0;
                $.each(responseOrderData, function(index){
                    rows++;
                    showOrderData += '<tr>';
                    showOrderData += '<td>';
                    showOrderData += responseOrderData[index].name;
                    showOrderData += '</td>';
                    showOrderData += '</tr>';
                    console.log(responseOrderData);
                });
                if(rows == 0){
                    showOrderData += '<tr><td colspan="7"><center><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i></center></td></tr>';    
                }
                $('.orderData').html(showOrderData);
            },
            timeout: 1000,
            error: function(error){
                console.log(error);
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to check updates every x seconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to somthing like `socket.io` to make real time updates and send data from server to client but you can do the task using JavaScript `setTimeout` or `setInterval` to refresh html content without reloading the page

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    getname();
})
function getname(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '../php/clas/name.php',
            data: 'type=getthename',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(responseOrderData){
                var showOrderData = '';
                var rows = 0;
                    if(rows == 0){
                    showOrderData += '<tr><td colspan="7"><center><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i></center></td></tr>';    
                }
                $.each(responseOrderData, function(index){
                    rows++;
                    showOrderData += '<tr>';
                    showOrderData += '<td>';
                    showOrderData += responseOrderData[index].name;
                    showOrderData += '</td>';
                    showOrderData += '</tr>';
                    console.log(responseOrderData);
                });

                $('.orderData').html(showOrderData);
                //wait 10 seconds after ajax called successfully
                setTimeout(getname,10000);
            },
            timeout: 1000,
            error: function(error){
                console.log(error);
            }
        })
    }
```